# Añadir cuenta de gmail en app para inicio de sesión

Tags: android, android-studio, gmail

lo que quiero es que mi app inicie sesión con mi cuenta de gmail que tengo vinculada en el móvil, así me evito el tener que estar poniendo usuario y contraseña. He visto que se usa el AccountManager para este tipo de uso, hice un método que devuelve todas las cuentas añadidas al móvil sale un alert con las cuentas pero no me deja seleccionar ninguna para que la añada como cuenta líder.

```
    public void login_gmail(){
    final ArrayList<String> gUsernameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");

    gUsernameList.clear();
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        gUsernameList.add(account.name);
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Seleccione su cuenta de correo");
    ListView lv = new ListView(this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                    gUsernameList);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int position,long
                id)
        {
            Log.d("Aceptar cuenta", gUsernameList.get(position));
        }
    });

    alert.setView(lv);
    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    final Dialog dialog = alert.create();
    dialog.show();

}
```

También he visto en cuentas si se trataba de una función oculta para la app pero tampoco, sabe alguien que puede faltar?

Añadí los permisos que dicen es imprescindible para el uso de esta función:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

/*------------------*/
Bueno investigando resulta que todo esa función que tengo lo puedo hacer de una forma más clara y ordenada, este código lo tengo en una función onClick si pulso el botón salen las cuentas que tengo y me deja elegir 1:

```
            try{
            Intent googlePicker = AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
                    new String[]{"com.google"}, true, null, null, null, null);
            startActivityForResult(googlePicker, PICK_ACCOUNT_REQUEST);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error de sincronización: " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
```

Con esta función se complementa el código de arriba y me devolvería si la sincronización es correcta.

```
    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_ACCOUNT_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        useremail = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
        Toast.makeText(this,"Cuenta sincronizada con éxito: "+useremail,3000).show();
    }
}
```

Si quiero que el email sea predeterminado como tengo que hacer? Si no cada vez que inicie la app me pide el email.

Comment: Supuestamente tengo que hacer que la app sea como una cuenta de correo. Yo añado la app en el movil apartado de cuentas y este me pide un usuario y contraseña y queda registrado. Pero no encuentro nada detallado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución para que las cuentas de gmail sean validadas y hagan un inicio de sesión automático sea con una cuenta gmail o mismo una cuenta creada manualmente se tiene que usar el accountManager para la creación de cuentas manuales y el SyncAdapter para la sincronización de las cuentas.